# AWS: Configuring Security Groups using hostname

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-security-group

Let's say I've a private subnet with bunch of EC2 instances. These EC2 instances make API calls with external partner, say api.somevendor.com, whose IP address might/will change. How do I configure my AWS security group to communicate to only this partner host?

Comment: This answer might help - https://stackoverflow.com/q/33339057/866021

Comment: @Adil B that question has to do with setting dynamic DNS for your own IP. This is how to deal with the changing  IP of an external service endpoint. You cannot run those scripts on a vendor external service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to open the security group to the IPs and ports provided by the vendor service. They should provide you  with that information, of course.

If you are concerned about what happens if the vendor *later* changes those IPs, you will have to change them again. Manually. It would be difficult if not impossible to script anything here.

A reputable vendor will provide you with notice of any upcoming changes to their service ips. Make sure you are on their email or technical notification list.

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo. That would be the ideal case i.e vendor can notify me about IP changes.

Comment: You bet. Most will have a customer email list, or technical notices list. Just make sure you are on it.  Kindly accept answer if you found it helpful.

Comment: Can this issue be solved using external/3rd party solution? Like Firewall?

Comment: No. There is no technology that would tell you what IPs have been assigned to an external service after the fact.  A human has to tell you, and you have to update the security group manually.

Comment: Probably no native solution in AWS. 
https://live.paloaltonetworks.com/t5/Configuration-Articles/How-to-Create-Custom-URL-Categories/ta-p/54355 perhaps would help here?

Comment: No, nothing anywhere. Only the provider can know their network and changes to their IP address scheme.

Comment: Could you not create a lambda to do a dns lookup and then update the IPs on the security group. Then run it at an approved schedule, hourly, daily etc